# Extract coordinates of raster cells that overlap with multilinestring

Tags: coordinates, extract, raster, multilinestring

I'm working with R and I have a raster (`population`) with population density data on each cell and a multilinestring (`border_365_366`) that represents an international border. I'd like to extract the coordinates of the raster cells that overlap with the international border.
Does anyone know how to extract this? I think one of the major issues here is that I'm working with a multilestring instead of a data.frame with coordinates.

```
> class(border_365_366)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

> class(population)
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")

[1] "raster"
> border_365_366
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
geometry type:  MULTILINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 27.32998 ymin: 57.52933 xmax: 28.21014 ymax: 59.46253
geographic CRS: WGS 84
                        geometry
1 MULTILINESTRING ((27.66656 ...

> population
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 21600, 34926, 754401600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01030751, 0.01046373  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -120.053, 105.9636  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : pop_new 
values     : 0, 107475  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by converting the line to linestring

`border_365_366<- st_cast(border_365_366,'LINESTRING')`